# how to get all the datastore results just with a key?

Tags: python, web-applications, google-cloud-datastore

I am pretty new to Python and GAE. Busy building a simple blog to learn. Was wondering, how can I get the datastore entries?

This is how my DB object looks like :

```
class BlogArticles(db.Model):
    author = db.UserProperty()
    article_name = db.StringProperty()
    article = db.TextProperty()
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

Can I get say author and article from passing the key to something like

```
db.get(key_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

aah figured it out :)

Here is how I did it...so simple.

```
    all_data = db.get(edit_article)
    article_name = all_data.article_name
    article = all_data.article
```